# Gradle does not resolve support library

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle

I am trying to use library called BetterPickers but can not even compile my project.

gradle.build contains this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.4.2'
}
```

But I keep getting this error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':App'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':App:_defaultFlavorDebugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:18.
>        Required by:
>            MyProject:App:unspecified > com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.4.2

I literally copied Gradle dependencies from their repository. And, even if I keep only the BetterPickers dependency, I still get the same error.

Comment: Since `support-v4` comes from your local Android SDK repository, what version do you have downloaded via your SDK Manager?

Comment: Latest. Support library rev. 19.0.1, Support repository rev. 3.

Answer (score 4):

You must install "Android Support Repository" and "Google Repository" from Android SDK manager for using support library

Comment: *Android Support Repository* is now called *Local Maven repository for Support Libraries*. It is found in the *Extras* section. *Google Repository* should not be necessary unless you wish to use any of Google's non-free libraries (Play, Android Auto).

Answer (score 0):

The build script instructs Gradle to get `com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+` from Maven Central. However, Maven Central doesn't have such a library (version). Hence the error.

From what I can tell, the Gradle Android plugin will take care of this dependency automatically, and it doesn't have to be declared explicitly.

`betterpickers` not only declares a dependency on `support-v4`, but also uses the old `apklib` library format. As far as I know, the Gradle Android plugin only supports the newer `aar` format. That's likely the cause for your problem.